# Google Maps directions text format

Tags: javascript, http, google-maps, map-directions

Ive noticed that sometimes gmaps directions display a turn like this:

> Turn right at Gallardo

and sometimes like this:

> Take the **1st left** onto Arregui

I need to always see the 1st,2nd,.. like in the second example. Is there a way to receive directions in this format always?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seriously doubt it. There's no mention of being able to control anything except the language.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapplets/reference.html#GDirectionsOptions

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so. It will give you 2nd left onto .... up to 3rd I believe after that it will just be the street name as per most directions you are given by maps / GPS systems and equipment. (The unwritten rules of the English road directions i guess)